# Left join with a limited amount of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm have the following situation. I have 3 tables: `artists`, `songs` and `stats`. I want to create a query that shows how many times the latests 10 songs from every artist have been played. Currently I have the following:

```
SELECT artists.id, COALESCE(SUM(stats.plays), 0)

FROM artists

LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id

    FROM songs as inner_songs
    WHERE inner_songs.artist_id = artists.id

    ORDER BY published_at DESC

    LIMIT 10
) AS songs

LEFT JOIN stats
ON stats.song_id = songs.id

GROUP BY artists.id
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
HINT:  There is an entry for table "artsis", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

Now I understand I cannot use `artists.id` inside de left join, but then the question remains. How can I do this query?

Comment: Awesome! If you want to post it as an answer, I'll give it the star @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that in two different ways:

A lateral join:

```
SELECT artists.id, COALESCE(SUM(stats.plays), 0)
FROM artists
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT id, artist_id
      FROM songs as inner_songs
      WHERE artist_id = artists.id
      ORDER BY published_at DESC
      LIMIT 10
  ) AS songs ON songs.artist_id = artists.id
  LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.song_id = songs.id
GROUP BY artists.id;
```

Or you could use a window function inside the derived table:

```
SELECT artists.id, COALESCE(SUM(stats.plays), 0)
FROM artists
  LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT id, 
             artist_id, 
             row_number() over (partition by artist_id order by published_at) as rn
      FROM songs
  ) AS songs ON songs.artist_id = artists.id AND rn <= 10
  LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.song_id = songs.id
GROUP BY artists.id;
```

The solution with the lateral join is most probably faster.

Comment: stackoverflow at it's best!